# Relations and differences between graphical models and stochastic networks?

Tags: networks

Do both graphical models and stochastic networks (e.g. http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/networks/) mean the same concept: there is an underlying graph,  each vertex corresponding to a random variable, and the edges representing the dependence between random variables?

If not, what are their definitions?

What are the relations and differences between graphical models and stochastic networks?

Thanks!